# Documentation for Android Interactive Notification Icon

Tags: mobilepush-android, react-native-marketingcloudsdk

We could find documentation for iOS Interactive Notification in this link https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/push-notifications/interactive-notifications.html.

But there is no documentation for Android (Java), can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/notifications/customize-notifications.html you'll just need to intercept the data and handle it the same as is done in iOS.